# Google analitycs and iframe

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

We have a website with iframe. 
In this website, some iFrames display dynamic questionnaires which coming from our different server.
We have declared both properties in Google Analytics (GA). (Main site and site retrieved through iFrames).
The sessions seem to be detected but NONE of the properties let us see the analytics page (with the % on each fields, heat maps and so on) in GA itself.
We can see analytics page (part of behavior menu) on the main site thanks to the GA Chrome extension.

We are looking for a way to detect the users behavior in the questionnaires contained in the iFrames.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [documentation for cross domain tracking with iFrames](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#iframes). It does not exactly cover your requirements (since you seem to use different properties for host page and framed page) but it is a good example for the postmessage interface that allows cross-domain communication in frames (as long as you control both pages). So you can use postmessage to send data from the framed form to the host page and set up a listener there that sends data to GA every time the listener is invoked (the linked docs have a code example, so I won't repeat that here).